# How to deserialize a Map<String, Object> using different type for different key with jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

There's a library class, the definition is:

```
class LibraryBean {
    public String tag;
    public Map<String, Object> attributes;
}
```

In my application code, I know every possible key for the `attributes` map, and the type of value of a certain key is fixed, for example, if the key is `"location"` then the value type is `Location`, if the key is `"timestamp"` then the value type is `Long`. Writing an `ArrayList<LibraryBean>` to a json string is simple, but how can I deserialize the json string so that the value recovers its type?

```
public void test(ArrayList<LibraryBean> sampleList) { 
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = mapper.writeAsString(sampleList);

        List<LibraryBean> recovered = mapper.readValue(jsonString); // what should I do here?

        // I'm sure sampleList.get(0).attributes.get("location") != null
        AssertTrue(sampleList.get(0).attributes.get("location") instanceof Location);
    }
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to have a map with different value types. Think about creating a map per type to avoid casting.

Answer (score 2):

Create your pojo for known fields:

```
class Attributes {
    private Location location;
    ...
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    ... getters and setters

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}

class LibraryBean {
    private String tag;
    private Attributes attributes;

    ... getters and setters
}
```